# Error Inserting data in android sqlite constraint failure

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to insert some data into android database but its throwing constraint error.I am not able to catch the cause of this exception.
this is my database creation java file.

```
package Database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class VendorTable extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ghartrends";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "fixingvendor";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String FIRM_NAME = "firm_name";
    private static final String OWNER_NAME = "owner_name";
    private static final String CONTACT = "contact";
    private static final String EMAIL_ID = "email_id";
    private static final String ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String WORKSCOPE = "workscope";
    private static final String VENDOR_ID = "vendor_id";
    private static final String ACTIVATION = "activation_code";

    public VendorTable(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_FIXINGVENDOR_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + FIRM_NAME + " TEXT," + OWNER_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + CONTACT + " TEXT,"+ EMAIL_ID +" TEXT,"+ ADDRESS +" TEXT,"
            +WORKSCOPE +" TEXT,"+ VENDOR_ID +" TEXT,"+ ACTIVATION +" TEXT               PRIMARY KEY"+ ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_FIXINGVENDOR_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public String GetActivationCode(){
        String activationcode;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT activation_code FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        do{
            activationcode=cursor.getString(8);
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());

        return activationcode;
    }

    public void addVendorInfo(String firmname,String ownername,String contact,String emailid,
                              String address,String workscope,String vendorid, String activationcode) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(FIRM_NAME, firmname); 
        values.put(OWNER_NAME, ownername);
        values.put(CONTACT, contact);
        values.put(EMAIL_ID, emailid);
        values.put(ADDRESS, address);
        values.put(WORKSCOPE, workscope);
        values.put(VENDOR_ID, vendorid);
        values.put(ACTIVATION, activationcode);

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
}
```

this is the error it is throwing

```
05-10 00:00:46.478: E/Database(527): Error inserting owner_name=kkhgfd    address=hgds workscope=jhfd vendor_id=TSSRANCY47MB08IEIDSB email_id=o@f.n  contact=9877654345 firm_name=hjgfds activation_code=0NA
05-10 00:00:46.478: E/Database(527): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
05-10 00:00:46.478: E/Database(527):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
05-10 00:00:46.478: E/Database(527):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
05-10 00:00:46.478: E/Database(527):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1582)
05-10 00:00:46.478: E/Database(527):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1426)
05-10 00:00:46.478: E/Database(527):    at Database.VendorTable.addVendorInfo(VendorTable.java:81)
05-10 00:00:46.478: E/Database(527):    at com.ghartrends.SignUp$1.onClick(SignUp.java:88)
05-10 00:00:46.478: E/Database(527):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
05-10 00:00:46.478: E/Database(527):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
05-10 00:00:46.478: E/Database(527):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-10 00:00:46.478: E/Database(527):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-10 00:00:46.478: E/Database(527):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-10 00:00:46.478: E/Database(527):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-10 00:00:46.478: E/Database(527):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 00:00:46.478: E/Database(527):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-10 00:00:46.478: E/Database(527):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-10 00:00:46.478: E/Database(527):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-10 00:00:46.478: E/Database(527):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As from the above two lines of the error you can notice no parameter which I am trying to store in database is null.

So where is the problem I am not able to configure.

Comment: I believe your database table already has the row with that primary key from previous run. Try Drop table query before you create your table in "onCreate" method. and run it again or change key for the next try.

Comment: which is line 81 ?? `Database.VendorTable.addVendorInfo(VendorTable.java:81)`

Comment: i have already provided the code   db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);   in onUpgrade method to drop the table if it already exists.

Comment: line 81 is `db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values)`;

Answer (score 1):

You define only `activation_code` field as a primary key that means that there can't be two or more records with the same value in `activation_code`. Exception occurs because you're trying to insert a record with `activation_code=0NA` for the second time.

If `activation_code` is not something like secret key, then I think the better way is to generate this field value based on other fields values.